# Music resources question collect,mine

Tags: discussion, questions

Although people agreed that "asset mines" [are OT](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/669/where-can-i-find-art-resources-questions-off-topic-not-a-real-question/), there are 3 music licensing questions which are really good and have valuable content.

See [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1045/where-is-quality-paid-game-music) and [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/8/where-can-i-find-free-sounds-for-my-game) and [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/18152/looking-for-a-royalty-free-sci-fi-sounding-song-thats-100-long-and-costs)

The basic question behind these is: "as an indie game developer, (mostly a first-timer), where can I get quality music and avoid being ripped off?"

There are many answers, many paths to go.  I initially tried the independent contractor route and found that frustrating and difficult -- simply because everything the artist pitched to me I didn't like, and I didn't know how to say that--- it's impossible to micromanage a creative and he's always going to, for better or for worse, put his own creative spin on it.  SO, I found, the best way to go is to license existing work for no more than $30/song.  Licensing existing work saves time, frustration, hassle, and you end up with a piece you actually like having paid money for.

(The preceding paragraph explains why such a post is valuable to a game developer!)

Comment: I'm a little confused about what you are actually asking -- are proposing that those questions are not off-topic? Only one of them was actually closed.

Comment: I'm proposing that we have 1 asset mine for music and music sources, answering the question "Where can I get quality music for my game (small studio)?"

Comment: It doesn't make sense. One I hate that people want art for free, it's likely that people want to eventualy sell their game but don't want to pay to make it. Artist put a lot of time and effort into what they do and want to be compensated as well. Not to mention the cost to them to make such art. Music isn't exactly cheap to make. Also, I write music for my games and my friend makes art. I'd love to contract my music out. If someone posts a question about music what's stopping me from going, hey me and my friends make music we'll write whatever you ask for $30.00/track. Seems silly to me.

Answer (score 1):

Content being "valuable" isn't the deciding factor on whether or not content is good for the site.  http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/

Likewise, your particular experience is, frankly, anecdotal.

I go into more detail about these kinds of questions w.r.t. community wikis here: https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/a/917/51

Comment: It's not really anecdotal.  I'm sure other small shops would experience a similar thing -- custom work is __expensive__ and takes more time to actually get than simply listening to a few online libraries.